# How do I center two child divs where each of those divs each have their own width? For example, one is a content area and the other a sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I am new to css - thanks in advance for the help.

I have a parent div with two child divs in it. I want it so that the parent div spans 100% of the window and then to have the combined width of the two child divs be a max-width and centered within the parent div.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 .learnings-main-content > * {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ef972d;
}

#learnings-main-content-area1 {
  /*left side where content will live*/
}

#learnings-main-content-area2 {
  /*right side where content will live*/
}
```

Thanks for the help, this has been a real pain and I am sure it's simple enough.

Comment: `the combined width of the two child divs be a max-width and centered within the parent div.` maybe explain this bit a little further, maybe add a picture of the end result

Comment: Sure thing! Here you go: https://ibb.co/Kqk6kHT

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
  
  .learnings-main-content {
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  display: flex;
}

#learnings-main-content-area1 {
  background-color:red;
  flex:1;
}

#learnings-main-content-area2 {
  background-color:blue;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="learnings-main-content">
  <div id="learnings-main-content-area1">
    sa
  </div>
  <div id ="learnings-main-content-area2">
    sa
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance so far! I've tried the options that folks have shared here and it's not quite what I am after. I've linked a screenshot below where you can get a better idea of what I mean. https://ibb.co/Kqk6kHT

Answer (score 0):

Just change your CSS class **.learnings-main-content** to the example below:

```
.learnings-main-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ef972d;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try and help. Here is a screenshot to help explain what I am after: https://ibb.co/Kqk6kHT